# What do I need to do to modify this to include indentation?

Tags: c#

I recently saw this code by @edplunkett and thought this would be useful in something I'm doing however I'd like to modify to include indentation:

```
static void Main()
{
var randomCrap = new List<Object>
{
    1, "two",
    new List<object> { 3, 4 },
    5, 6,
    new List<object> {
        new List<object> { 7, 8, "nine" },
    },
};

randomCrap.PrintAll();
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void PrintAll(this Object root)
    {
        foreach (var x in root.SelectAll())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Object> SelectAll(this object o)
    {
        //  Thank you, eocron
        if (o is String)
        {
            yield return o;
        }
        else if (o is IEnumerable)
        {
            var e = o as IEnumerable;
            foreach (var child in e)
            {
                foreach (var child2 in child.SelectAll())
                    yield return child2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yield return o;
        }
    }
}
```

How easy is it to add indentation each time an `IEnumerable` is encountered so that you'd get this:

```
1
two
  3
  4
5
6
  7
  8
  nine
```

Something like a starting indent of 0 which increases by one every `IEnumerable` encountered?

Comment: Hahaha! `randomCrap`. I know where that's from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it pretty easily with tuples:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void PrintAll(this Object root)
    {
        foreach (var x in root.SelectAll(""))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Item1 + x.Item2);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<(string, Object)> SelectAll(this object o, string indentation)
    {
        //  Thank you, eocron
        if (o is String)
        {
            yield return (indentation, o);
        }
        else if (o is IEnumerable)
        {
            var e = o as IEnumerable;
            foreach (var child in e)
            {
                foreach (var child2 in child.SelectAll(indentation + "  "))
                    yield return (child2.Item1, child2.Item2);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yield return (indentation, o);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here's a pre-C# 7 version (untested, but should work):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void PrintAll(this Object root)
    {
        foreach (var x in root.SelectAll(""))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Item1 + x.Item2);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, Object>> SelectAll(this object o, string indentation)
    {
        //  Thank you, eocron
        if (o is String)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(indentation, o);
        }
        else if (o is IEnumerable)
        {
            var e = o as IEnumerable;
            foreach (var child in e)
            {
                foreach (var child2 in child.SelectAll(indentation + "  "))
                    yield return Tuple.Create(child2.Item1, child2.Item2);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(indentation, o);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JamesCurran Yeah. A little different implementation, but the same idea.

Comment: @itsme86 thanks for this but I cannot get this to work.  When I copy and paste I get errors such as `Method must have a return type` at `SelectAll` keyword on line `public static IEnumerable<(string, Object)> SelectAll(this object o, string indentation)`.  I also get `syntax error => expected` after line `yield return (indentation, o);`.  You seem to have it working so I am missing something obvious?

Comment: @Monika It requires C# 7. If you're using an older version of VIsual Studio, that could be your problem. You can do it with older versions, but it's a little uglier. You can change the return type to `Tuple<string, object>` and instead of `yield return (whatever, whatever)` you'd do `yield return Tuple.Create(whatever, whatever)`. Never mind, I'll just update my answer. EDIT: Updated.

Comment: @itsme86 Thanks :) you're a star.

Answer (score 0):

That would be quite a large change.  Right now, it is passing to the Function, and returning from it, single objects.  You would have to change that to pass and return two things: th eobject, and the indent level.  It could be done, butit would destroy the elegance of @edplunkett's design.

UPDATE: Actually, with Tuples, it's not that bad after all::

```
static void Main()
{
    var randomCrap = new List<Object>
{
    1, "two",
    new List<object> { 3, 4 },
    5, 6,
    new List<object> {
        new List<object> { 7, 8, "nine" },
    },
};

    randomCrap.PrintAll();
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void PrintAll(this Object root)
    {
        foreach (var x in root.SelectAll(0))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", new string('_', x.indent),x.obj);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<(Object obj,int indent)> 
                     SelectAll(this object o, int indent)
    {
        //  Thank you, eocron
        if (o is String)
        {
            yield return (o,indent);
        }
        else if (o is IEnumerable)
        {
            var e = o as IEnumerable;
            foreach (var child in e)
            {
                foreach (var child2 in child.SelectAll(indent+1))
                    yield return child2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yield return (o, indent);
        }
    }
}
```